# What is a Software Framework and what are the advantages of software frameworks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, frameworks, web-frameworks

When I was googling, I just saw that there are a number of software frameworks present. Like this,

```
ASP.NET - MonoRail
Java - Google Web Toolkit
JavaScript - Backbone.js
php - CakePHP
Python - Django
Ruby - Ruby on Rails
```

So my quection is this.

Why we use frameworks and why we spent time to learning frameworks instead of learning more advanced techniques of the programming language?

Are there any disadvantage of using a framework? (specially reduction of speed when using server-side or client-side frameworks)

Comment: What do you mean by "learning more advanced techniques of the programming language"?

Comment: @Sayse I meant that, learning every inch of the programming language that we use instead of reserving time for learning new framework..! Because I know that those frameworks are also written on the particular language and we can make our own frameworks best matches for our work instead of using and learning another one. Thank you for your help..!

Comment: Simple. Do you really want to be spending effort on fixing bugs and maintaining underlying frameworks when you don't really need to?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So frameworks are really just collections of functions and libraries pieced together to make it easier to perform a particular tasks.

In the case of your question, you're looking primarily at web frameworks. Which make it easier to write web servers in these languages. Python Django is a great framework because it handles all of the web stuff for you. (http requests and traffic routing) and allows you to simply specify what code will run when your app takes certain requests.

So in short, frameworks try make it easier to do certain things. Of course different people think different ways to do things are easier, so that's why we have so many different kinds of frameworks.

Feel free to ask any questions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Short & Sweet answer..! Thank you very much...!